# Form submit refreshing page, not submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, pug

I am having trouble with submitting this form. I use the same form layout elsewhere on my website. So I know its not a layout issue. Every time I click the *login* button, it refreshes the page without submitting anything. If the fields are empty, they are supposed to show a message under them stating that you need to enter something in. However, when I click the login button with nothing in the fields, it still refreshes the page and does nothing else.

client side:

```
.container
    .row
      .col-lg-8.col-lg-offset-2.col-md-10.col-md-offset-1
        form#loginForm(name='login', novalidate='')
          .row
            .col-md-6
              .form-group
                input#username.form-control(type='username', placeholder='Your Username *', required='', data-validation-required-message='Please enter your username')
                p.help-block.text-danger
              .form-group
                input#password.form-control(type='password', placeholder='Your Password *', required='', data-validation-required-message='Please enter your password')
                p.help-block.text-danger
            .clearfix
            .col-lg-12.text-center
              #success
              button.btn.btn-xl(id='loginBtn', type='submit') Login
              br
              br
              a(href='/blog/register') Register!
```

javascript handler:

```
$(function(){
  $("#loginForm input").jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
        // additional error messages or events
    },
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
        // get values from FORM
        var username = $("input#username").val();
        var password = $("input#password").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/login",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                user: username,
                pass: SHA256(password)
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
                // Success message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append("<strong>Rerouting you to home page... </strong>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append('</div>');

                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
            error: function() {
                // Fail message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append($("<strong>").text("Sorry, we dont have these matching credentials in our database"));
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
        });
    },
    filter: function() {
        return $(this).is(":visible");
    },
  });

  $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).tab("show");
  });
});
```

I'm not even getting anything server side because nothing is submitting. I have tried `console.log()` in the function, but I didn't even get that. Its not even getting to the function.

Comment: Are you sure this  $("#loginForm input") shouldn't be  $("#loginForm")?

Comment: @TonySamperi Positive, I use the same thing with my register form.

Comment: mmm...let me do some research

Comment: Is that function in an external .js file? If so, try emptying the browser cache and retry.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Yes it is. I cleared the cache and retried but still nothing.

Comment: And no error in console? No console.log in `submitError` or in `submitSuccess`?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette It's not even getting to the function. I tried to log right after `$(function(){` and didn't get anything.

Comment: Ok... Type this directly in the console command line : `$.fn.jquery;`, it is supposed to return the jQuery version you use.

Comment: You can also try this `console.log(typeof($));`, which is supposed to return "function". If "undefined", the problem is jQuery not loaded.

Comment: Maybe on the very last line you're missing a () near }) ? from this `});` to this `})(); `

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette When I do `$.fn.jquery;` It returns `"1.12.4"`. When I do `console.log(typeof($));` I get undefined.

Comment: Well, straith in the console commande line, `typeof($)` is enought... My bad. If you had "function", then "undefined"... It's ok

Comment: If the addition of `()` on the closing bracket does not work.... Try to replace `$(function(){` with `$(document).ready(function(){` and close it with `});`... Just to test that too.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Yeah that still did nothing.

Comment: Do you have a live link to share? I would like to see that!

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette https://theglasshousestudios.com/blog?

Comment: Man! Your `script` tags are commented out in your `head`!!! All except jQuery. `html5shiv.js` and `respond.min.js` are commented out... And there is nothing else but `jquery.min.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. I am sorry for this trouble. It was simpler then we all thought. At the end of my `blogIndex.jade` file I had.

```
// jQuery
script(src='../vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js')
// Bootstrap Core JavaScript
script(src='../vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')
// Contact Form JavaScript
script(src='../javascripts/jqBootstrapValidation.js')
script(src='../javascripts/contact_me.js')
// Theme JavaScript
script(src='../javascripts/clean-blog.min.js')
```

I also had an

```
//this will change it was for testing purposes 
-var loggedIn = false
if !loggedIn
    //show login stuff
else
    //show blog posts
```

The script tags where just one space indented into the else statement so none of those were being loaded. As @LouysPatriceBessette pointed out. it was a pug error, caused by me.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the external .js file where this jQuery script is...
**Is not loaded in [your page](https://theglasshousestudios.com/blog?).**

I think this is all due to some [Pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) syntax issues somewhere in your `head`.

I have to mention those Pug related errors on the produced HTML:

`<!--if lt IE 9-->` should be `<!--[if lt IE 9]-->` and there is no `<![endif]-->`

And below, the HTML syntax is invalid, due to the parenthesis and comas...
It looks like Pug hasn't compiled that part.

```
<!--script(src='https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js', integrity='sha384-0s5Pv64cNZJieYFkXYOTId2HMA2Lfb6q2nAcx2n0RTLUnCAoTTsS0nKEO27XyKcY', crossorigin='anonymous')-->

<!--script(src='https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js', integrity='sha384-ZoaMbDF+4LeFxg6WdScQ9nnR1QC2MIRxA1O9KWEXQwns1G8UNyIEZIQidzb0T1fo', crossorigin='anonymous')-->
```

The issue *probably* is related to [Pug comment syntax](https://pugjs.org/language/comments.html).

Comment: This would make sense if it were html. I don't know if you are familiar with pug or not but you typically use a `layout.jade` file and then extends `content` that in your ex: `index.jade` file. The layout is just simply the `head` and `body block content`. I use this layout for both my login and register. The register form works perfect. But, the login is still not working. I don't see how it could be something is the `head` if my register works fine

Comment: Nope... I'm not familiar with Pug. ;)